# QGIS coordinates show Y,X instead of X,Y

Tags: qgis

The status bar on QGIS 3.26.2 (Windows 11) is showing my planar coordinates as **Y,X** instead of **X,Y**.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: please add a screenshot...

Comment: And edit your question to state what CRS your project is using.

Comment: Please Mention the Coordinate system that you are using.

Answer (score 6):

You can customise the order in the project properties.

`Project > Project Properties > General > Coordinate and Bearing Display`

[image]